# Looking for Bolo story where farming tractor Bolo uses pesticide on aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, bolo-universe

I'm trying to find the name of a short story with a Bolo that was converted to a farm tractor. Its world is invaded by aliens and not having weapons it has to adapt its farming tools to fight back.

Also, what Bolo book is that in?

Comment: I can't find a plot synopsis to confirm it, and I don't remember the pesticide detail myself, but I think you might be looking for "Final Mission", which was published in both *Rogue Bolo* and *The Compleat Bolo*. The most detailed description I found is in an Amazon review: "about an outdated, decommissioned Bolo who gets a second chance to live and fight like he was designed to."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be 'The Farmers Wife' pubished in 'The Triumphant'. In this story the Bolo 'Digger' is left on a planet when the colonists leave due to the approach of hostile aliens. Digger is left behind and combats the 'Agricultural Pests' using bio-warfare techniques.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm sorry that I forgot about this for so long.

Comment: https://www.baen.com/bolos-iii-the-triumphant.html